# Looping url from DB for simplexml_load_file

Tags: php, mysql, xml, algorithm

I need to looping XML URL into simplexml_load_file in PHP.

I don't understand because if i write an URL from any variable, the script is work, but if i load the url from database the script is die.

This code work:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("www.blablabla.com/file.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
                           /*other script, elaborate the response*/
```

And this code work:

```
$url = "www.blablabla.com/file.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
                          /*other script, elaborate the response*/
```

Now, i load a url from database, and pass this value into simplexml_load_file.

```
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT url from wp_rezdy_products");
while($result = $query->fetch_row()){
$url = $result[0];
echo $url ."<br>";

$xml = simplexml_load_file($url) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
*/ other script, elaborate the response */
}
```

Why this method doesn't work and die the method with message error?

The **echo** is ok, return a value of url, why into simplexml_load_file no?

Comment: This should return syntax error, unexpected '*'`  after your `$xml = simplexml_load_file($url) or die("Error: Cannot create object");` line

Comment: Not sure if whitespace is an issue with `simplexml_load_file()` but you can try `$xml = simplexml_load_file(trim($url))...` just in case

Comment: */ other script, elaborate the response */ - this is a abbreviation of my other rules, for elaborate the script, is not present in the code